# Magento Go Home Page(CMS) Product Layout Display List View

Tags: magento, layout, product, magento-go

I m creating Webstore in Magento Go My Webstore Home Page(CMS) Contain 3 Column Layout

Layout Update XML is below.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
         <action method="addPriceBlockType">
             <type>bundle</type>
             <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>   
             <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
         </action>
    </block>
    <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new">   
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>                
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="reports/product_compared" name="home.reports.product.compared" template="reports/home_product_compared.phtml" after="product_viewed">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>  
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.viewed</alias></action>
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.compared</alias></action>
</reference>
```

Product Display in home page With Grid Layout.
But I Need To Display Product With List Layout How To Change Product Layout And Which Line Of Code I Change.
Thanks For The Help In Advance I Hope The Solution is Avilable for that

Answer (score 0):

go to the `catalog/product/new.phtml` and change the css class and id, may be it will help you

Comment: Thanks For The Suggestation But In Magento Go We Are Not Editable Any Kind Of File...

Comment: @BhargavPatel sorry for wrong suggestion, but you can over write the used class and id bye using your custom css editor of your theme